# PHP Select Count and Left Join where

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

Im not sure if it´s possible to combine SELECT COUNT + Left Join on this way but it would be very helpful for me.

This is my code whitout Left Join attempt:

```
$pp = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_tgp WHERE idt='$zaznam[id]' AND ( partic='' OR partic='y' OR (partic=='n' AND $zaznam[logoff]=='n'))"), 0);
```

I have to get COUNT of players from the specific training (WHERE idt) `where partic = '' OR partic = 'y' OR (partic = 'n' AND TRAINING[logoff] = 'n')`

Problem is that `TRAINING[logoff]` is value from different table. Am I able to make Left Join to get this value into Select Count to Where clause based on `app_tgp.idt = app_training.id`?

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: try SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_tgp 
LEFT JOIN app_training on app_tgp.idt = app_training.id
WHERE idt='$zaznam[id]' AND ( partic='' OR partic='y' OR (partic=='n' AND $zaznam[logoff]=='n'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here $zaznam[logoff]=='n'. There must be any column name where you have written  $zaznam[logoff]. For Applying Left Join you should do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_tgp t1 LEFT JOIN app_training t2 on t1.idt = t2.id WHERE t1.idt='$zaznam[id]' AND ( t1.partic='' OR t1.partic='y' OR (t1.partic=='n' AND t2.your_column_name_here=='n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do `LEFT JOIN` claue. In that case, Your `training` table must have any column that means any information from columns `app_tgp` table. If so, you can build query:

> `$pp = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*)
>                             FROM app_tgp
>                             LEFT JOIN different_table ON app_tgp.column = different_table.column
>                             WHERE app_tgp.idt='$zaznam[id]'
>                             AND ( app_tgp.partic='' OR app_tgp.partic='y'
>                               OR (app_tgp.partic=='n'
>                                   AND different_table.training[logoff] = 'n'))"), 0);`

There in `JOIN` claus, `app_tgp.column = different_table.column` - columns must have indentical information